# Go json.Unmarshall() works with single entity but not with slice

Tags: json, go, slice

I'm using Go for a simple http client. Here's the entity I'm unmarshalling:

```
type Message struct {
    Id int64
    Timestamp int64
    Text string
    Author User
    LastEdited int64
}

type User struct {
    Id int64
    Name string
}
```

A single entity looks like this in JSON:

```
{
    "text": "hello, can you hear me?",
    "timestamp": 1512964818565,
    "author": {
        "name": "andrea",
        "id": 3
    },
    "lastEdited": null,
    "id": 8
}
```

Go/json has no problem unmarshalling the single entity:

```
var m Message

err = json.Unmarshal(body, &m)
if err != nil {
    printerr(err.Error())
}
println(m.Text)
```

However, if the return of the endpoint is multiple entities:

```
[
    {
        "text": "hello, can you hear me?",
        "timestamp": 1512964800981,
        "author": {
            "name": "eleven",
            "id": 4
        },
        "lastEdited": null,
        "id": 7
    }
]
```

And I change my corresponding Unmarshall to work on a slice of structs, Go throws an error:

```
var m []Message

err = json.Unmarshal(body, &m)
if err != nil {
    printerr(err.Error()) // unexpected end of JSON input
}

for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {
    println(m[i].Text)
}
```

What gives?

Comment: The JSON is malformed. It's probably missing the closing "]" and possibly more.

Comment: Show the code used to read the HTTP response.

Comment: embarrassed to say that I simply was requesting the wrong URL and getting an empty response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me (try it on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UCY4RyrzAs)), where are you getting the payload data from? sounds like that's truncating it.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Message struct {
    Id         int64
    Timestamp  int64
    Text       string
    Author     User
    LastEdited int64
}

type User struct {
    Id   int64
    Name string
}

func main() {
    body := []byte(`[
    {
        "text": "hello, can you hear me?",
        "timestamp": 1512964800981,
        "author": {
            "name": "eleven",
            "id": 4
        },
        "lastEdited": null,
        "id": 7
    }
]`)

    var m []Message

    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v") // unexpected end of JSON input
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {
        fmt.Println(m[i].Text)
    }
}
```

running it gives this output

```
hello, can you hear me?
```